# Can't enter BIOS with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot

So I've been reading about a thousand posts, all of which have a different button/combination to enter the BIOS. My [laptop](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1ZRe8jOCYBuNkHFCcq6AHtVXaE/Ultra-Thin-Keyboard-Cover-Skin-Protector-for-15-6-HP-OMEN-15-CE003LA-HP-OMEN-15.jpg) doesn't seem to have a working F12 button, it will only switch airplane mode on and off.

Comment: Entering BIOS is not OS related. So it doesn't matter which OS is installed. Why are you trying F12?

Comment: I would google your laptop make and model to find the bios key/s.  If you have grub showing at start up, should also be an option for system settings(not sure of wording) that will take you to bios also.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change boot priority?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208417/how-to-change-boot-priority) - [BIOS keys](https://askubuntu.com/a/1084586/) for many common laptop models