# How do I reinstall Windows 10 on my Ubuntu laptop?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, windows, bios

I need some help with something that I've been trying to figure out how to do successfully for weeks now. I don't know how to revert back to Windows. I want to go back to Windows and **then** reinstall Ubuntu to dual boot. Without Windows, I wasted a ton of money on different programs. And I admit, I'm not the brightest person you'll meet. I tried multiple tutorials online, looked at other threads and answers, but nothing worked. Whenever I boot from USB, it'll show my HP logo without Ubuntu. The first time it did that, I thought it worked. **But** it went to a black screen, and then said "Booting in insecure mode" meaning that it was booting into Ubuntu. I don't know how to solve this, and at this rate, there's no hope for me getting Windows back. Any help is appreciated.

~Fairtem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu) and [How to change boot priority?](https://askubuntu.com/q/208417/)

Comment: What access do you have to a copy of Win10?  Do you have an installation disk?  Do you have a Win10 key-code?

Comment: You didn't exactly specified what have you tried yet hence it could be hard for us to point out a solution. If wiping out entire disk is an option I recommend doing that then go for fresh installation, do make a backup before. If that isn't an option kindly elaborate the steps you have taken so far.