# Change boot order to boot from USB stick - Function keys not working during boot

Tags: boot, 18.04, live-usb

I need to start my computer several times to successfully boot into Ubuntu 18 04.

That is why I would like to reinstall Ubuntu.

I got a USB Stick with ISO current Ubuntu ISO image mounted as media in GNOME, however the system never asks for an install upon restart. When I press F2 nothing happens. When I press F12, my screen flashes black / purple in sync with my key attenuations and then yields the following error.

[image]

How can I simply change the boot order so that upon restart Ubuntu will boot from the USB?

I am using BIOS, I believe:

:~$ sudo efibootmgr
EFI variables are not supported on this system.

I installed my system using a USB stick with ISO file.

Comment: That error complains about samba - not mission crucial.. The boot sequence can be changed in your bios (uefi?) only..  Some lines talk about kernel crashes. You should elaborate what kind of UEFI/bios you have- and how exactly did you install your system? Use the **edit** link below your answer..

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I added the information but suspect that I am not precise enough... Hope to find a solution anyway.

Comment: Funny - I fixed your image and you broke it again... I fixed it again... But your info is not sufficient. Could you paste the output of `lspci -vv` and add it to your question? Usually you should not see the console if you made a "standard" install. Your boot sequence can still be changed in the bios...

Comment: P.S The command can only be issued if you can somehow reach your OS, either the installed one or the Live USB.  In order to start from USB you need to change the boot order in your BIOS..

Comment: Can you add to your question make and model of your computer, or motherboard make and model if custom build?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/q/674441/) and [How to change boot priority?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208417/how-to-change-boot-priority)

Comment: If your computer is booting with Syslinux press shift when booting, at the language screen press F6 then a space then type `only-ubiquity` that should take you to install. If booting with grub, press `e` at the grub menu, at the end of the `linux` line type `only-ubiquity` that should also take you to install.

Answer (score 0):

### Boot USB from Internal Drive's GRUB Menu

You can use your internal GRUB to boot a ISO9660 Ubuntu install USB if the USB's bootloader is having problems.

Add the following menuentry to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` and then run `sudo update-grub`

```
menuentry "Ubuntu - flash drive" {
 search --set=root --fs-uuid 2020-07-31-16-51-12-00
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux ($root)/casper/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash ---
    initrd ($root)/casper/initrd
}
```

Where 2020-07-31-16-51-12-00 is the UUID of the USB's root partition.

This should work with a USB made using Etcher, Startup Disk Creator, dd, mkusb, Disks or other ISO9660 cloner.