# Cannot access BIOS in Lenovo G580

Tags: boot, bios, system-call-fastboot

Tried to enter in Boot setup using F2 and updated grub .But not able to enter into bootsetup nothing work.After pressing F2 it direcly get into Ubuntu .If it is fastboot pls guide me to disable it . As its my second day in ubuntu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change boot priority?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208417/how-to-change-boot-priority) Maybe try pressing the Novo button.

Comment: Power it off completely. Hold down F2 then power it up. When `Please Wait` appears on the screen, release F2.