# Cannot install Ubuntu 20.04 along with Windows 8

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, windows-8, usb-installation

I have Toshiba satellite C50-A-1G6 PC which has a non recoverable Windows8.

When I try to install the Ubuntu 20.04 , from USB ISO file. It checks first my disks and says: no errors found.  After  selecting the language and the keyboard,  I get error message:
You need at least 8.6 GB disk space to install Ubuntu. This computer has only 4.1 GB.
This computer has 750 GB hard disk.
The installation does not let met to go the part where I can choose the option, to
clean up the entire hard disk and install only Ubuntu to it (I have done this many times
earlier with broken Windows)

I am asking if somebody knows how I can prepare my hard disk with an .ISO application
or in ‘try Ubuntu’ mode.
Is there an other way to fix this with open source or  a low price tool?

Below are the details:

There was Window 8 , which is broken and cannot be recovered with Windows 8 or 10 ISO installations , which I can download from the Microsoft site. Also I have tried MS-DOS Diskpart with the help I get from Google.

I can open Ubuntu in the "Try Ubuntu" mode and it works perfect and tried to fix with Boot-Repair from: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
But it does not help, my problem stays.

When I run it I get the attached report. I don’t see any errors or fixes in it,
The report is visible in
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/RNztvZzNzv/

Thanks for any help or hints.

Comment: Run `gparted`. Can you see your disk? Boot-repair is unrelated. What option are you choosing to install? Choose replace Windows with Ubuntu.

Comment: And there is no "Ubunto 20" release.

Comment: Ubuntu has both releases using *yy* (*year* of release) format, and *yy.mm* (*year.month* of release) format, but they are different products.  Ubuntu Core 20 for example does not contain a desktop, is usually used on headless devices (appliances, in the cloud, VMs etc), where as Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop is probably more what you want (there is also Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server, but a desktop release is closer to a windows system).

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools

Comment: I suggest that before the installation you choose "Try Ubuntu" and launch the "Disks" application and try to format (erase) the disk.   Considering that you don't know why your Windows installation failed, consider that you might have a hardware problem that might prevent you from installing Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your HDD is dead. So you need to replace it first.

Comment: Although you are probably right, these seems more like a comment than an answer. For example your answer could highlight areas of the boot-repair log that leads to this conclusion.

Comment: Thanks for all help

Answer (score 0):

Boot into BIOS and ensure your 750GB drive is visible. See: [How to change boot priority?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208417/how-to-change-boot-priority/1298460#1298460) as a reference.

If it's visible in BIOS then try `testdisk` to see if it can be repaired. I could not find **exact** instructions. But I found related instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootSectorFix):

### Step 1 - Boot on a liveCD or liveUSB

Boot your computer on a Ubuntu live-CD or live-USB, then choose "Try Ubuntu".

### Step 2 - Install TestDisk in the live-session

Once in the Ubuntu live session, install TestDisk this way:

- Connect internet
- Open the Software Center, in the top bar click Edit -> Software Sources -> enable the Universe repository
- Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and type :

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y testdisk && sudo testdisk
```

### Step 3 - Use TestDisk

- Via the arrows and the Enter key, go to the [No log] menu,
- then select the disk where the broken partition is,
- then select [Proceed],
- then choose the type of partition (generally [Intel]),
- then[Advanced],
- then select the broken partition with [Boot], it will display something like :

```
 Boot sector
 Status: Bad

 Backup boot sector
 Status: OK

 Sectors are not identical.

 A valid NTFS Boot sector must be present in order to access
 any data; even if the partition is not bootable.

 [  List  ]  [Backup BS]  [Rebuild BS]  [  Dump  ]
```

7. Check that you have "Status ok" below "Backup boot sector"
8. select [Backup BS].

Done

---

As mentioned these are not **exact** instructions. If you get stuck at a certain point when adapting these instructions to repair your disk, you can update your question.

Comment: The problem was that my hard disk is broken. It still worth to by a new one.

Comment: @user1164511 It's always worth upgrading a hard drive to an SSD for performance reasons even when it is working. Only you can decide if your machine is worth keeping around though.