# How can I force a boot from a USB stick

Tags: boot

Is there a way to force my system (Dell Inspiron) to boot from a USB stick (or any other bootable medium)? A restart brings it to Grub, which isn't supposed to be there.  Ctl-Alt-Del used to be the ticket, but not any more.

Comment: Isn't it usually pressing the `Esc` key whilst the system is booting to enter the Setup Utility then selecting `Boot` from the menu selecting the USB device from there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change boot priority?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208417/how-to-change-boot-priority)

Answer (score 7):

For every Dell Inspiron I’ve used, it’s f2 to enter the bios menu.

Other common options are f10, f12, and Esc.

When you switch the machine on, it usually flashes up very briefly with what key to press to enter setup. Holding that key down as soon as you’ve turned the power on usually works.

If f2 doesn’t work and the machine doesn’t show anything, it will usually work to tap f2 / f10 / f12 / Esc repeatedly immediately after powering on.

Once in the bios, there’s a menu for boot priority - set USB to the first priority and it should do exactly that.

Comment: +1, If you cannot find which key to press or tap, please read the user manual of the computer (via the internet, if there is no paper copy).