# ubuntu 22.04 boot usb dosn't override windows boot

Tags: boot, usb

I created ubuntu 22.04 boot usb (new) using balenaEtcher. boot opts don't appear holding down f12, starts windows automatically. (new ryzen 7 desktop, new usb), windows 11 home

Comment: You possibly need to change the boot order in bios.

Comment: This is a question about your hardware and isn't determined by Ubuntu (or any other operating system). If you're not sure how to access your motherboard BIOS/UEFI/Firmware, usually there is a splash screen that informs you what you need to press during boot. In absence of this, you'll need to check the documentation from your motherboard manufacturer.

Comment: F1 is the default key - try changing the boot order using F1 to enter the UEFI

Comment: @france1 From where exactly you got that info from? It usually ISN'T F1 but some other F key or others. And in any case this is hardware depended as clearly stated above. And obviously "new ryzen 7 desktop" says absolutely nothing useful for determining which one is the correct key to access either UEFI settings interface or the one-time boot / boot override menu.

Comment: @ChanganAuto usually the F1 key should work even if it isn't listed in the options menu.

Comment: Issue resolved, frequent pressing "delete" allowed access to BIOS, thereafter it was easy.  Thanks to all who responded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change boot priority?](https://askubuntu.com/q/208417/)