# Ubuntu 22.10 won't boot with DVD drive in SATA. Says "AHCI unavailable" Boots fine when DVD unplugged

Tags: dvd, msi

DVD worked on MSI Z490 board with intel i7.
With MSI Z690 board and intel i7, it won't boot with DVD plugged into SATA. Message "AHCI unavailable."

Comment: is it because in your boot menu in BIOS you have the CD drive set as the default boot media?

Comment: Your question is rather unclear; any details in the title should also be provided in the question as not all browser setups show the title when when your question is viewed (*not all of us large screen PCs*). It seems to be a *firmware* setting that is incorrect, which is also specific to your motherboard (ie. a hardware question, not OS question).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change boot priority?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208417/how-to-change-boot-priority)

Comment: Boot priority does not include DVD drive.  It may be the later MSI board.  Booted with MSI Z490 and DVD worked.  With MSI Z690 it did not work.

Comment: Am new to this.  Sorry to put in redundant question.  But I added the tag "boot" which better described my problem.  Does this site only deal with Ubuntu and not with its interaction with hardware?

Comment: Is the AHCI a driver for the DVD?