# Reaching setup bios Asus B560M-A

Tags: boot, keyboard, asus, bios

I am embarrassed to ask this question but I can't get into the BIOS of this MB to change the boot order for my Ubuntu server 22.04 installation! In the manual the keys are <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>Del</kbd>. I've tried both of these several times without success (starting 'pecking' as soon as I press the start button). I've tried a PS2 Keyboard and a Wireless (not Bluetooth) keyboard.
The manual then says to try following if above doesn't work!

1. Press <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> simultaneously
2. Press the Reset button on the system chassis
3. Press the Power button to turn the system off, then back on. Do this option only if you failed to enter BIOS setup using the first two options.

It then says: "After doing either of the three options, press the <kbd>Del</kbd> key to enter BIOS."

Just wondering if anyone else has tried any of these 3 options? They seem strange to me, particularly the third. These instructions relate to "after POST", so does that mean after I've logged into Ubuntu server? Am I being too risk averse, as I expect these instructions are mainly directed to Microsoft users?

Comment: The key needed to be pressed depends on the *firmware* for your device, of which you gave no specifics. That detail can actually change (*extremely rare!*) when you perform firmware updates, so are you looking at the correct version of the manual for your used firmware? Either way I have decides that require me to hold a key whilst box is off & device turns on, others that are annoying in that they give so little time for me to press a key I'm needing to do it many times.. I usually just boot a recent release on thumb-drive which offers me a menu option to boot into *firmware settings*.

Comment: How to access BIOS dpes not depend on the OS.  It is a hardware issue. "These instructions relate to 'after POST'. So does that mean after I've logged into Ubuntu server? " No. It means post initial loading of bios and before grub comes into play/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change boot priority?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208417/how-to-change-boot-priority)

Answer (score 0):

Section 2.2 in the manual will explain another option to try.

Id also sugest you review the Support page for any BIOS firmware updates.

You can clear the cmos and it should force an error offering to enter BIOS on next boot.There should be two jumper/pins on the board labled CLRTC located right by your front panel header.

***Caution*** Again this will Clear everything and reset the entire BIOS back to factory defaults.

This may help:
https://www.reddit.com/r/ASUS/comments/okjfic/why_i_cant_enter_on_bios_i_have_a_b560a_gaming/

BIOS Manual:
https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1200/PRIME_B560M-A/E18905_PRIME_B560M-A_v2_UM_WEB.pdf

Support page:
https://www.asus.com/motherboards-components/motherboards/prime/prime-b560m-a/helpdesk_download/?model2Name=PRIME-B560M-A

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the helpful suggestions. I think I have a solution but it may be restricted to the B560M-A motherboard. The goal was to change the boot order to enable a USB boot but it was impossible to enter the BIOS by the usual F2 or DEL route before POST because the delay before POST (logo on screen) was too short (but the default is adjustable up to 10 seconds).
After POST and login I entered ctrl + alt + delete. This reboots however it does so slower thereby allowing entry of F2 or DEL to 'get into' the BIOS. This is because, after an AC failure (or something similar I guess), 'fast boot' reverts to 'normal boot' for that boot only. Once in BIOS the delay before POST can be adjusted to suit a slow old man like me. My research was helped by an online BIOS Manual for this MB which did not come with the machine: "Prime / TUF Gaming Intel 500 series BIOS Manual".