# I don't even know where to start at this point. Reboot?

Tags: reboot

I was attempting to "mount" a disk so that I could access it through regular means without going into "Other Locations", because some programs won't let me access it through those means. I was following along with a YouTube video, and now it's like I'm on a whole new desktop, or like everything got wiped.

At this point I just need to reinstall Ubuntu, but I can't find any kind of recovery option. I tried putting the thumb drive that I had originally used in and restarting the PC. I can't find any tutorials on terminal commands. I tried the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> on boot...nothing.

I'm new to Linux if that isn't obvious, but I understand that there's alot of stuff I'm used to from working on a windows my whole life that just don't translate. But tell me I'm wrong. There has to be a way to just reboot the system and start over?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change boot priority?](https://askubuntu.com/q/208417/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a bootable USB, (I will use HP machine for ex.) Power the machine off. Insert the bootable USB, turn the power on, Tap "escape" key, and if you are taping it when you see the flash screen, it will go into BIOS, you can select a boot option there. Select the USB you plugged in. Ex: Sandisk, select it hit enter and it will boot up. You can look online for the keys to push for Dell, Acer, etc to get into BIOS. (I have been doing the usb boot for 3 days straight now) good luck

Comment: This actually ended up working after the fifteenth time or so lol, and because of what I had done it ended up being a little convoluted cause I had to go into the bios and disabled the mounted drives for it to recognize the usb, but I was able to get Ubuntu reinstalled.