# Can't install 23.10

Tags: system-installation

Have a Microsoft Surface running Linux Mint; trying to install Ubuntu 23.10. I have UEFI and Secure Boot turned off but thumb drive is not recognized at boot. Boot skips right past the installed thumb drive. I'm mystified. Any help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change boot priority?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208417/how-to-change-boot-priority) and [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/1190764/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)