# How do I alter/customize the GRUB boot menu for Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, grub2

I use a shared computer, so I need to make it user friendly for my-less-than-computer-knowledgable friend

currently have Ubuntu 12.10 installed

I would like to change the GRUB menu so that Windows 7 is at the top of the list (thus allowing the automatic timeout to automatically select it on startup) and Ubuntu down below

I've already used the information used at { [How do I change the GRUB boot order?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order) } and that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default boot by editing the grub config:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Change the line *GRUB_DEFAULT=0*  so that it reflects which grub boot line is the one you want to boot off: eg *GRUB_DEFAULT=2* etc.

You will then need to update the grub boot menu so that this change takes effect:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Having to select the correct OS from a men is hardly *unfriendly*, but if you really have to...

Comment: I altered the GRUB_DEFAULT=0 line to GRUB_DEFAULT=5 as that is the line Windows is on, did update-grub and update grub2. still has cursor on Ubuntu (first line)

Answer (score 0):

Edit */etc/default/grub* and change **GRUB_DEFAULT** value from 0 to the number of your friends Windows 7 in grub boot menu.

Then Run `sudo update-grub2`