# Ubuntu 12.04.1 Installation problems (boot-up/partition)

Tags: 12.04, grub2, boot-partition

After Windows cleanup, defrag and creating a partition of unallocated free space from `c:` drive; started out with 3 partitions:

- Windows Storage 200MB
- Windows OS 162GB
- Windows Recovery 13GB
- with about 131GB unallocated free space

Inside of Ubuntu 12.04.1 Installer (32-bit, though installed on a 64-bit system) – booted through a USB stick:

- Deleted Windows Recovery partition to free up an extra partition; unallocated free space up to about 145GB
- Added partition of 30GB for Ubuntu ext 4 `/` mount
- Added partition of 8GB for Linux `swap`
- Added remainder (~107 GB) into final partition for storage at `/home` mount (started out with FAT32)

Tried to continue installation – DENIED because:

> The file system type FAT32 cannot be mounted on `/home`, because it is not a fully-functional Unix file system. Please choose a different file system, such as `ext2`.

Thus, I switched to `ext4` for the `/home` mount storage partition, hoping that I could change it later with Gparted or find some other work-around to enable me to share my folders (docs, music, photos, etc.) between Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04.1.

The installation proceeded, yet never asked which partition I wanted to choose to place Ubuntu within. Upon conclusion of install, it auto-rebooted only to have the system freeze up. I forced shut down and manually booted. Instead of giving me the Windows 7/Ubuntu option, it first booted directly into Ubuntu.

Next, I loaded and ran Boot Repair, which informed me that the problem was now resolved.  What that provided (after reboot) was the purple GRUB screen with a Ubuntu boot option at the top and a Windows 7 boot option several options down. This does work, but it is not the setup that I have seen (when I test ran Ubuntu through `Wubi`)  that showed a one or other choice (Ubuntu or Windows) in a more attractive 2-option layout screen (prior to the GRUB screen).

Questions:

- How do I know if Ubuntu was installed in the appropriate directory?
- Is it installed in `sda3`?
- Also, as it appears (to me anyway), it looks as though my `sda4` (that was to be my storage `/home` mount partition) is now an extended partition with the `swap` (in `sda5`) and the `/home`  mount partition for file storage/sharing (in `sda6`). Is this correct for my needs?

Essentially, I would like:

1. The boot option to be in the concise choice (b/w) screen PRIOR to loading through GRUB (is it possible to edit GRUB to achieve this objective?), and
2. My partition structure to be correct to enable a work-around for file sharing (Windows/Ubuntu) through a common storage partition (if incorrect for my needs, is it possible to edit within Gparted?).

Listed below please find my `fdisk` and `parted` terminal information:

```
john@john-HP-G71-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for john: 

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x8d769ec6

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      409599      203776    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          409600   341301247   170445824    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       341301248   399894527    29296640   83  Linux
/dev/sda4       399896574   625141759   112622593    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       399896576   415518719     7811072   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       415520768   625141759   104810496   83  Linux

john@john-HP-G71-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA Hitachi HTS72323 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  210MB  209MB   primary   ntfs            boot
 2      210MB   175GB  175GB   primary   ntfs
 3      175GB   205GB  30.0GB  primary   ext4
 4      205GB   320GB  115GB   extended
 5      205GB   213GB  7999MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
 6      213GB   320GB  107GB   logical   ext4
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine.

- **Q:** How do I know if Ubuntu was installed in the appropriate directory?

When you selected `/` as the mount point for sda3 Ubuntu installation knew that's where it should put the system files for Ubuntu.

- **Q:** Is it installed in sda3?

So yes, Ubuntu is installed in sda3.

- **Q:** Also, as it appears (to me anyway), it looks as though my sda4 (that
  was to be my storage /home mount partition) is now an extended
  partition with the swap (in sda5) and the /home mount partition for
  file storage/sharing (in sda6). Is this correct for my needs?

There can be only 4 primary partitions. That includes the extended partition sda4 which contains the logical partitions sda5 (swap) and sda6 (/home). This is as it should be. There is no way to make 5 primary partitions.

**GRUB vs Windows Bootloader**

The WUBI install uses Windows bootloader. This is the simple one you had seen before. A full install, as you have just completed uses GRUB. There are reasons for these choices that I don't fully understand. However, I know trying to replace one with the other is a bad idea. So you may have to get used to the GRUB. Yes you can customize the GRUB menu, [but that is another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226744/how-do-i-alter-customize-the-grub-boot-menu-for-ubuntu-12-10).

**File Sharing and common storage**

Out of the box, Windows does not recognize ext4 partition, but Ubuntu recognizes ntfs. So when you boot Windows you won't have access to the Ubuntu /home.

When you boot Ubuntu you will have access to your Windows partition. However, Ubuntu uses a different system for storing file and folder ownership and permissions information (That's why /home cannot be in NTFS or FAT32). So when you put a file of Ubuntu origin in the NTFS partition some of the ownership and permission information may be lost. This may be fine for music, and photos at home, but is a potential problem for sensitive documents and personal configuration files.

Search this site for specific suggestions on how to share files between Windows and Ubuntu on the same machine. Look at [Windows Ubuntu dual boot - Share files between OS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223655/windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-share-files-between-os) for how to keep documents and files in NTFS partition and link them to folders in Ubuntu.

Hope this helps.