# grub boot order problems after update

Tags: grub2, upgrade, dual-boot

My grub menu went through rather extensive changes after the last update.  It started booting to my old 12.04 entry by default.  Where this gets confusing is that there is no longer a 12.10 entry in grub.cfg.

I installed and tried the grub-cfg as mentioned in [How do I change the GRUB boot order?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order) and everything appeared to go ok but when I rebooted to test, the boot menu looked the same and the behaviour was the same.

I restarted grub configure and the changes it indicated that my changes had happened.  I looked at /etc/default/grub expecting that it would have changed after save from the grub configure tool but it had not.  I then modified `/etc/default/grub`:

```
< GRUB_DEFAULT="Ubuntu"
---
> GRUB_DEFAULT="Ubuntu, with Linux 12.04 3.2.0-24-generic"
because the entry in /boot/grub/grub.cfg that I needed for the boot looks like:
"Ubuntu" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os ...
and ran sudo update-grub as instructed.  

grep for '^menu' in grub.cfg gives me the following:
menuentry "Ubuntu" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os ...
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 12.04 3.2.0-24-generic" --class ubuntu ...
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
menuentry "Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)" --class windows -...
menuentry "Windows Recovery Environment (loader) (on /dev/sda3)" ...
```

The menu at boot still looked as it had before and still booted to the old 12.04 system and does not reflect the info in the grub.cfg file.

What is going on??

Thanks.

Comment: This should be a comment, but I'm not yet allowed to leave comments. Your symptoms sound just like the ones I've been having for about two weeks now. After literally dozens of reboots, I am confident in stating that grub is broken. Just today, I modified my grub.cfg file by hand at least six times but could not get grub to even show the menu to me. However, when I booted off a USB drive, THEN it showed me the *hard drive's* Grub menu. It also destroyed something (the MBR? the /boot directory? the initrd.img file?) on the USB stick, because the next reboot was off the hard drive again, and the

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `sudo update-grub`. It will look for all OS on File system and make changes in grub.cfg file. You can directly see the entries in grub.cfg file via `cat`. If you are comfortable making editing system files, take a backup of grub.cfg file and change the order of OS entries in grub.cfg file.