# How to prioritise dual-boot to Ubuntu over WIndows?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, startup

As the titles suggests, I have no idea how to change the dual-boot to making ubuntu load over windows, any help would be appreciated

Comment: See if this helps you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order.

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve this, you will need to edit your GRUB boot priority order.

You can do it within the terminal, editing grub configuration, as  explanained at this link: http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2011/09/25/how-to-change-boot-order-in-ubuntu-11-04/

Or, you can install a graphical tool like **grub-customizer** (others available, crawl synaptic), to help you in the process. Some useful info about it can be found here: [How do I change the GRUB boot order?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order)

Hope it helps!