# How do I set Ubuntu to my default boot?

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, windows, partitioning

I have Windows 7 and 8 installed on my laptop, I just installed Ubuntu. 
It normally boots up in Windows 8, how do I change that?

Comment: Which boot loader are you using? The one Ubuntu installs or the Windows bootloader?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the GRUB boot order?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order)

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl-Alt-t, in the terminal type

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

press Enter and enter your password.

find the line that says

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
```

change 0 to a number that corresponds to the boot menu entry you want as default. First entry is 0, second is 1 etc..

You can also change the timeout value in the following line.

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

If set to 0 you will not see the boot menu anymore.

When you're done, save and close the file.

Back in the terminal type:

```
sudo update-grub
```

enter password (there's no feedback when you type it in), press enter, reboot.

enjoy