# how to customize grub

Tags: boot

I am dual booting windows 8 with Ubuntu 12.10. The default grub looks okay but I would like to change the order of the boot and customize it. Please help as I am a newbie and do not have much experience with Ubuntu or any other Linux distributions.

Comment: Have you looked at this post? [How do I change the grub boot order?](http://askubuntu.com/q/100232/62483)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to edit grub use next command in Terminal: `gksu gedit /etc/default/grub`. Or use [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer) - a graphical grub2 settings manager.