# Ubuntu desktop and server

Tags: system-installation

I installed Ubuntu server on a peripheral computer to a networks as I wanted to example it to a friend as a possible alternative. I also installed the desktop after but it wont boot the desktop automatically as I installed it second. How do I change it so the Desktop boots automatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the grub boot order?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the terminal way.

```
sudo -i gedit /etc/default/grub
```

There is an option in the text file. GRUB_DEFAULT=0 . This implies the first line of the grub list while booting. Count from 0 to the OS you want to be default. For example;

0 - Ubuntu Server

1 - Recovery Options

2 - Windows os

3 - Ubuntu Desktop

You should set GRUB_DEFAULT=3

Than give `sudo update-grub2` command.
Restart.