# How can I stop my computer from automatically booting into Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I installed Ubuntu 13.10, and after rebooting my computer does not go into grub and just straight up boots into Ubuntu. I am currently dual-booting windows 7 with Ubuntu, so I would like to know how I can still access windows 7.

Comment: Rebooting may not be enough - try shutting down instead. Do you get prompted with anything like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cf/GRUB_with_ubuntu_and_windows_vista.png)?

Comment: No, that is what I was looking for but it did not appear.

Answer (score 2):

Use an easy to use GUI app called grub-customizer.

You can install it by:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

In the *settings*: if you set/add the *GRUB_TIMEOUT* directive and change the value to -1, you will cause GRUB2 to pause until you make a decision, which seems to be what you're looking for.

[image]

Sources: 
[How do I change the GRUB boot order?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order)

https://superuser.com/questions/395373/how-do-i-prevent-grub2-from-automatically-booting-into-an-os

---

Alternatively,

In case your grub2 is hidden and never shows then try [Boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Open a new Terminal, then type + enter:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
```

and then enter

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

[image: Boot Repair]

See advanced tab and check unhide boot menu.

[image]

Comment: I tried both these suggestions, and neither seemed to work. When I used boot repair it made me have an error where I could not even boot into Ubuntu, so I had to re-install Ubuntu. But it still does not seem to work.

Comment: @Daniel Really important to know these error messages. Can you give more information on what exactly does not work? Edit your question by adding more information such as: What you expected to happen,What actually happened and exact error mesg etc...