# Bring Windows XP to the last option instead of first option

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, windows-xp

Is there any way to install XP after installing Lubuntu 13.10 and bringing Ubuntu to the first position in the Grub menu as I am using XP only for my School Work and I am using Ubuntu for all my work. If, there is a way, then I want a detailed answer as i am using linux for the first time.

Comment: see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order

Answer (score 0):

You can use Grub customizer:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Now open Grub Customizer and change the order.