# How to repair Ubuntu bootloader?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, grub2, uninstall

I installed *grub2* to dual boot another OS alongside my *Ubuntu 12.04 LTS*, but decided against it at the last second.

So I just did `sudo apt-get purge grub`, and it said it had purged all grub files, so I rebooted and guess what appears? *Grub*.

How do I get rid of it?. I'm worried that the only way to get rid of it is to format my hard drive, or worse, even that won't help.

### EDIT:

Basically I am only running *Ubuntu 12.04 LTS* and would like it to go back to doing what it used to do, which was booting itself with no annoying grub UI, just the quick <kbd>F12</kbd> boot menu BIOS stuff then boot.

Comment: grub is what ubuntu uses to boot, do you want to disable Ubuntu as well? or do you just want to hide the boot selection screen?

Comment: Removing Grub means that your system won't boot, unless you have another bootloader - what other OS are you using? You can hide the boot selection screen easily.

Comment: @wilf To me it looks like the OP wants just to hide the selection, like you said. You might want to  write up the steps in an answer :)

Comment: @TravisG. If indeed Ubuntu already uses grub to boot then I suppose that hiding the selection screen is probably what I have to do. If you could tell me how to do that or at least refer me to a post that would be great! Also my GRUB_HIDDEN-TIMEOUT is already 0

Comment: Use `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0`. I may have just answered it for you :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use get Grub to boot straight into Ubuntu without waiting by setting the value

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

In your `/etc/default/grub` file.  This will select the default option on the list (I assume this is Ubuntu for you) and go straight in.

Comment: That may be the wrong option - http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Simple-configuration

Answer (score 0):

### To repair the bootloader:

To restore Grub to your system, if you have removed, or part-done another installatiob, installed Windows, etc:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
```

Where `sdX` gives your hard disk entry under `/dev`. Usually this is `/dev/sda`, but it can vary if it is on an external drive or something. You can find the disk entry in:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

After, that run this *(May not be required, but it should not hurt:)*

```
sudo update-grub
```

You can check with:

```
sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sdX
```

---

### To make Grub nor show on boot:

Edit`/etc/default/grub`:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and add/change this line:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

then run this to update the changes:

```
sudo update-grub
```

When it is runnning you will get something like this:

> USERNAME@HOSTNAME:~$ sudo update-grub
> [sudo] password for USERNAME: 
> Generating grub.cfg ... Found linux image:
> /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-15-generic Found initrd image:
> /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-15-generic Found linux image:
> /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic Found initrd image:
> /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic Found memtest86+ image:
> /boot/memtest86+.bin
> Found Fedora release 20 (Heisenbug) on /dev/sda2
> done USERNAME@HOSTNAME:~$

The Ubuntu kernels would likely be the `linux` and and `initrd` entries, other Operating Systems should appear after `Found ...`

Manual on configuring grub [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Simple-configuration)

---

### Other useful stuff:

You can also set this in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=3
```

Which would mean that it would not display the selection menu for 3 seconds, allowing you to use it if you need to by pressing <kbd>Any Key</kbd>, and then it would boot.

If you want the kernel that is selected in the menu to always be the default selection, add/change these lines:

```
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
```

Remember to run `sudo update-grub` to update the changes *(or it won't do anything)*, and there is [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Simple-configuration) for more options.

For easier and more advancded configuration of Grub, you may want to use [Grub Customizer](https://askubuntu.com/a/100246/178596)

If you did remove `grub`, you may need to reinstall it with `apt-get`. Grub is the bootloader for most Linux systems, this problem likely would of been caused by the Debian Grub overwriting the Ubuntu Grub.

Comment: I have set my grub file to those settings and when I rebooted it still went to the line bash terminal thing, so it hasn't worked :( Any other ideas

Comment: If you get a flashing underscore `_` after GRUB, that is filling the time *after* Grub boots the kernel, and before the splash screen *(`plymouth`)* appears. You can't really remove that, just ignore it. It is there to show it is working and doing something - it is better than staring at a blank screen.

Comment: I can't quite remember but when I did it I had to do all the set root=(hd0,1) stuff and /vmlinuz and all that to get into Ubuntu. Is it possible I haven't set a default kernel and if so how do I set it to Ubuntu?

Comment: You shouldn't need to select it... It is just showing what it has found.

Comment: I will try again and see what happens and I will look out for the flashing underscore then report back

Comment: Ok it came up with a flashing underscore but nothing happened so I had to boot it myself again, I really can't think what it is doing, but if there is a way to restore to a previous Ubuntu (I haven't backed anything up) that would be helpful... Any suggestions?

Comment: If you need to select the kernel to boot from in GRUB, you need select that, and boot. Then add the lines `GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true` and `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved`. Then update the changes. This will mean that upon selecting the kernel on the next boot, it will from then onwards boot that by default.

Comment: how do I choose the default kernel to boot, I'm a bit of a newbie so I'm not really sure what to do :/

Comment: Go to the Grub selection menu you were so desperate to remove, and select the entry `Ubuntu, with kernel whatever`. It may be under `Advanced Options for Ubuntu`. When you mean 'restore the previous Ubuntu' what did you do exactly to stop it booting - did you try installing another Ubuntu as well, but cancel it? And are you able to use a graphical interface? Normally you don't need to enter BIOS to boot Ubuntu...

Comment: Ok basically I wanted to dual boot Ubuntu with Debian (long story dw) and decided against it at the last second. So, I simply did sudo apt-get remove grub, which it said i had done, but then when I rebooted my computer it came up with a strange text-based grub bash terminal. I can get into Ubuntu and use the GUI but it takes a load of code that I don't want to have to type in.

Comment: So the title to the question should be *'How to repair Ubuntu bootloader after installing Debian?'* ? :-S

Comment: Ok I didn't know that Grub was the original bootloader sorry, but is there a way to get it to auto boot again?

Comment: Edited answer - you may want to edit your question :-)