# How do I force Kubuntu 12.10 to boot in 32-bit mode (Linux 3.2.0-34-generic-pae)?

Tags: boot, grub2, 64-bit, kubuntu, 32-bit

Just upgraded from 12.04 to 12.10, on my ancient 32-bit Dell Latitude C-400 laptop.

After the install, I restarted my machine as directed by the OS and got a blank screen. The computer appeared to be running fine, just no display.

Booting in GRUB gave me the option of two versions (as well as recovery modes for both):

1. Linux 3.5.0-45-generic
2. Linux 3.2.0-34-generic-pae

Apparently 3.5 is the 64-bit version, and 3.2 is the 32-bit version. When I choose 3.2.0, the system completes the boot sequence as it should, complete with functioning video display.

How do I force Kubuntu to boot in Linux 3.2.0? If it's as simple as changing the order of the versions listed in GRUB, how do I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about `Linux 3.5.0-45-generic` being 64-bit. That would not possible if your Laptop only supports 32-bit. Putting that aside, your question is about how to set default boot entry. Take a lookt at [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer). There is one good tutorial here: [How do I change the GRUB boot order?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order). The `accepted` answer there can be a bit confusing. You can just follow the second answer, which I paste here:

You can also change the grub default boot entry from the command line without having to install any additional tool.  This won't change the order in the list but it will allow a different OS to boot by default, which sounds like what you may want anyway.

First, make a backup copy of `/etc/default/grub`. In case something goes wrong, you can easily revert to the known-good copy.

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak
```

Then edit the file using `vim` or the text editor of your choice.

```
sudo vim /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line that contains `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` and set it to `GRUB_DEFAULT=x` where `x` is the index of grub menu item to which you would like to boot to by default. Note that the menu items are zero-indexed. That means that the first item in the list is `0` and that the sixth item is actually `5`.  So to boot to the sixth item in the list, the line would read `GRUB_DEFAULT=5`.

Additionally, if you want to use a kernel in the "Previous Linux Versions" menu, you'll want to change GRUB_DEFAULT=0 to GRUB_DEFAULT="2>x" (make sure to include the quotations), where x is the placement of the old kernel on the sub-list (assuming the "Previous Linux Versions" is third on the main list). Remember that the list always begins counting at 0.

Then build the updated grub menu.

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: That did the trick. The kernel I needed was in a sub-menu called "Advanced Options for Ubuntu", and I didn't know how to reference it. Thanks. As for Linux 3.5.0-45-generic not being 64-bit, you might be right. I looked it up and thought that was what I read.

Both Linux 3.5.0-45-generic and Linux 3.2.0-34-generic-pae were installed when I upgraded from 12.04 to 12.10. Any idea why the first would not work, but the second does?

Comment: My first guess woul be that you don't have compatible packages (i.e. drivers and other Kunbuntu packages) that are compiled with the newer kernel. Did you have some interruption during the upgrade?

Comment: There was no interruption during the 12.10 upgrade.  I did experience a problem before the upgrade, when updating 12.04. It's possible all the packages for that update were not installed.  Now in 12.10, I get the KDE desktop, but no Dash option, even though Dash is installed. If I understand correctly, Unity is the desktop that uses Dash, but I can't find any reference to Unity in my installed packages.  Thanks for the followup.

Comment: You can try `sudo apt-get install kde` to reinstall KDE environment. `kde` is a meta package for KDE environment. Doing the above command will install all default packages for KDE. You can read more about `Meta packages` [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages). PS: If you accept my answer as the answer for your question, mark my answer as `accepted` by clicking on the "Check" mark near the vote up/down arrows.