# grub EFI bootup order

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have two versions of Linux installed in different partitions on a 2013 iMac and I'm using rEFInd to perform the initial booting, which then starts up the grub EFI binary that lives on a dedicated MSDOS partition.

If I select grub, it seems to scan all my partitions and discovers a kernel at /dev/sda8 (latest release) and /dev/sda9 (long term support). It then gives me the option to boot into each kernel, but orders them in alphabetical order: meaning the *old* kernel is the default. But I want the new kernel to be the default.

There do not appear to be any config files for this /boot/efi/EFI/ version of grub... the /boot/grub/* files are specific to each installation.

How can I set the display order (or at least the default choice) for grub EFI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following question and answers:

[How do I change the GRUB boot order?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order)

An alternative is to ditch GRUB entirely; rEFInd can launch your kernels directly, assuming they're 3.3.0 or later. You may need to install an [EFI filesystem driver](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/drivers.html). With that done, you can edit the `refind.conf` file to change the `default_selection` option to specify which kernel you want to boot by default.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I messed up... I installed the older distro second and its grub overwrote the more recent distro, placing itself as preference! Obviously the menu entries are hard-coded into the grub EFI binary that is deployed at /boot/efi (I thought it was auto-detecting). Doing a grub-install and grub-update from my new distro fixed the problem. I'll mark you as answer since you're technically correct ;-)

Comment: Actually, GRUB 2 reads menu entries from its `grub.cfg` file, which can be loaded from the ESP or from the Linux `/boot` partition, depending on how GRUB is configured. The `grub.cfg` file is usually regenerated when you re-install GRUB or when you run tools like `update-grub` (which will be done when you update your kernel, among other things).