# How to set an image generated by update-initramfs to be loaded by default

Tags: boot, kernel

In my adventures in trying to revert a kernel upgrade (it broke my wifi for some reason), I was able to generate a boot image for the previous kernel (`#update-initramfs -c -k 3.11.0-17-generic`)

I deleted the newer kernel boot image for good measure (`#update-initramfs -d -k 3.11.0-19-generic`)

Now every other boot my machine goes into panic mode because it can't find the `3.11.0-19` kernel version, and I have to hard reset, which puts me into boot menu where I can select the proper version.

My question is, how can I make `3.11.0-17-generic` my default boot kernel (at least until I figure out what caused the issue with `19` and can upgrade again)

**Edit:**

For future visitors, images created by `update-initramfs -c` should be visible in grub (for me its under `Advanced Options for Xubuntu`). Just follow one of the answers in [How do I change the GRUB boot order?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate of that question, but I do think some GRUB configuration is required. At least try `sudo update-grub` EDIT: if you haven't already done it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I hadn't tried update-grub.
When I did try it though, it possibly made things worse (appears to mangle the default configuration in grub. At least before update-grub I could manually edit the configuration to load the older image)