# Set the GRUB Default OS: Dual-boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 14.04, windows-7

I'm running a dual-boot system, having installed Ubuntu 14.04 after the Windows 7 installation. GRUB, as you already know, sets Ubuntu as a default/first Operating System.

The question is: how can I set GRUB to load Windows 7 as a default/first OS?

Cheers,

Answer (score 4):

The **graphical way** as mentioned before:

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu-1404/

The Application is not in the Repositories of your Software Center by default. That's why you need to add a Personal Package Archive (PPA) and update the sources.

Hit <kbd>Super/Win</kbd> to open Dash, type *soft* and choose *Software & Updates*. Go to *Other Software* and click *add*. There you can enter the new resource `ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer`. After confirm and close you would be asked to reload. Now you can search for in `grub-customizer` in your Software Center and install it.

Without clicking, you can install it in your terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt update
sudo apt install grub-customizer
```

---

Or just **change boot order** in `grub` config on your own. 
All of the following commands need sudoers permissions. You can hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gksu` (maybe not installed by default) in front of every command or open a **terminal** with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> an use `sudo` to run commands with needed privileges

First of all backup the old config with

```
cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak
```

then open the open grub file with your favourite editor e.g. gedit

```
gedit /etc/default/grub
```

or directly open it within your terminal with vi or vim (if you know how to use)

```
vim /etc/default/grub
```

and edit the GRUB_DEFAULT Value to the item you want to select by default (counted from zero), save the file an run

```
update-grub
```

After that a new Configuration is built and you can reboot to test.

Multiple Q/A:
[How do I change the GRUB boot order?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order)

Comment: @sonyqs: kudos to you for the instruction to save the old grub config. This is often forgotten.

Answer (score 1):

Try using grub-customiser it is available in software center.

Under List configuration tab > Move windows to the top as shown in below image and save it

[image]

Under General settings tab > default entry > predefined- entry 1 by position
[image]

Comment: it works, thx. although I could not find grub-customiser in software center, I've found download instructions here: https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same need.
I followed the following steps:

- `sudo apt-get install startupmanager`
- Enter password and hit 'Y' to complete the installation.
- Once installed, start the *StartUp-Manager*. You can do so by searching and selecting it from the Dashboard.
- There in the *'Boot options'* menu you will find second option as *'Default Operating System'*
- It will be a drop-down menu. Select Windows operating system
- Restart your computer and it will consider Windows as Default OS.