# Boot Ubuntu automatically

Tags: dual-boot

I have a HP laptop running Windows 8.1. It currently automatically boots up into Windows 8.1, so to  load Ubuntu I have to press the ESC on startup key to go into boot options so I can access Ubuntu.

Ideally I want to either run Ubuntu by default (preferred), or for a boot menu to appear on startup if the first option isn't possible. Any ideas whether this is possible please?

Comment: This question seems to have an anwer elsewhere on askubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order

Comment: I think he is using EFI. Have you tried to go in the BIOS and change boot order there and save? (Key to enter bios changes from laptop to laptop, in mine it's F2)

Comment: Open command prompt with administrative privileges. Type the following command bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi This will replace Windows boot manager with Grub and Ubuntu will work fine.