# How can I automatically switch the boot order in grub2?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have Ubuntu 14.04 Server and Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop installed.

My task is:

- restart running Ubuntu Desktop (with crontab)
- boot into Ubuntu Server
- do backup etc.
- restart running Ubuntu Server
- boot into Ubuntu Desktop

I have tried [How do I change the GRUB boot order?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order) (edit the file `/etc/default/grub`) but I can only change the boot order in running Ubuntu Server, not in running Ubuntu Desktop.

But I have to change the boot order every time the system changes. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On both systems a script in autostart:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

and in `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=4
```

So everytime a system starts it reinstalls grub, puts itself on the top of the boot list and the other system on place 4. When  a system switches the boot order switches too.