# How can I edit the boot listing in ubuntu14

Tags: grub2

I want to hide some of the list from boot menu.Is it possible?

Comment: Edit how? Add something? What? Remove something? Please [edit] your question and explain what you want to do and why.

Comment: This may be of help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can:

Here's an example GRUB config file (this is an earlier version of GRUB, but the concept is the same):

```
default=0
timeout=10
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz

# section to load Linux
title Red Hat Enterprise Linux (2.4.21-1.ent)
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.4.21-1 ro root=/dev/sda2
    initrd /initrd-2.4.21-1.img


# section to load Windows
title Windows
    rootnoverify (hd0,0)
    chainloader +1
```

To remove the windows option, just comment it out like this:

```
default=0
timeout=10
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz

# section to load Linux
title Red Hat Enterprise Linux (2.4.21-1.ent)
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.4.21-1 ro root=/dev/sda2
    initrd /initrd-2.4.21-1.img


# section to load Windows
#title Windows
#    rootnoverify (hd0,0)
#    chainloader +1
```

Make sure to comment out everything underneath that option.  They should all be tabbed out one or two, so you can kind of see what's what.