# How do I make my computer automatically boot into Windows instead of Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I have dual-OS's on my computer and when I turn it on it will automatically boot into Ubuntu.  I am only able to get into Windows if I manually make a selection in what I think is grub (I am new to this and have almost no idea what anybody is talking about most of the time - please treat me like a 3rd grader).  I would like to have it so that unless I manually select Ubuntu when I boot up it will by default go in to Windows 7.

Anyway I simply want to turn on my computer, do nothing, and have it boot into Windows rather than Ubuntu. How can I do this?

Running W7 and 14.04 by the way.

Comment: You need to change the boot order. How to [change grub boot order](http://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order)

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order

Comment: Welcome to the community! Just to answer your sub question; Yes; what you are looking at is called the "Grub".  This question is fairly common so please take a look at the answers provided above!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
alther the grub
```

and enter this in the terminal:

```
sudo -I
gedit /boot/grub.cfg
```

and then type this in where its run the windows:

```
fi   uuid=ntfs  set root=c:/
     echo 'starting mokmanager'
     nfts mokmanager.efi
     ehco 'starting windows'
     ntfs c:/windows/win.exe
```

and it might work fine this way.