# log error: "[drm:gen8_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* The master control interrupt lied (SDE)!"

Tags: kubuntu, 15.10, interrupts

I get this error after installing Kubuntu 15.10 when restart Kubuntu:

```
[   74.873008] [drm:gen8_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* The master control interrupt lied (SDE)!
```

I use kernel 4.2.0-16 and KDE 5.4.2.

This error wil show on black background when i startup, shutdown and reboot.
after that system work normal , nothing happen.

output command:

```
$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 19ad
        Kernel driver in use: i915
```

How to fix this error ?

Comment: And what is the real problem?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: When i startup, shutdown and restart , screen display above error on black background, after system work normal , nothing happen.

Comment: i have just edit my question. thanks @Pilot6

Comment: If system works well, it is not a problem. You can report a bug regarding that message.

Comment: The problem is that this log spams syslog and if there is another display connected and disconnected, I finally end up with a black screen and have to disconnect another display and restart the system. There are bugs already reported, it seems this message has some connection with those bugs.

Comment: Yes, but i have not another display connected, there is only startup, shutdown or reboot the system.

Comment: Linked bug reports from deleted answer: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1488719 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1492632

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by an interaction bug between some version 3* / 4* [Linux kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) and Intel/Broadwell [kernel module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loadable_kernel_module) **i915.ko** / **i915_bpo.ko**.

"ko" stands for "kernel object". The name of the buggy module varies between **i915.ko** and **i915_bpo.ko** depending on your Linux kernel version (each kernel version works with a different version of this kernel module).

The i915/i915_bpo file is a kernel module which operates as a device driver for Intel/Broadwell GPU (Graphical Power Unit) devices: in your case, it's the device driver for your VGA-compatible controller *Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)*.

For more info about this bug, please read and subscribe to this bug report:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1520040

Related bugs:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1488719
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1503541

Currently, the latest stable (working) kernel module is **i915_bdw.ko**, but in order to use it you'll have to install kernel **3.13.0-36-generic** and use it as your system's default kernel.

In order to install kernel **3.13.0-36-generic**, run this shell supercommand:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get check && sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.13.0-36-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-36-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-36 linux-headers-3.13.0-36-generic linux-signed-image-3.13.0-36-generic linux-tools-3.13.0-36 -y
```

---

If your Ubuntu repository does not have kernel **3.13.0-36-generic**, you can manually download and install the necessary files:

- Open a shell terminal window.
- Run this command in order to check your operating system's architecture:

  ```
  uname -i
  ```

  If the answer to the above command is **x86_64** (or anything having **64** in it), your system architecture is **64-bit**. Otherwise, the above command will return ***i386*** (or something like it, e.g. i586, i686...), thus your system architecture is ***32-bit***.
- Run this command in order to create and access a temporary installation folder:

  ```
  sudo mkdir /tmp/kerneldebs && cd /tmp/kerneldebs
  ```
- Now you need to download the 3 necessary files for your system's architecture.

  - If your system's architecture is **32-bit** (i386), run this supercommand:

    ```
    sudo wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.13.11.6-trusty/linux-headers-3.13.11-03131106_3.13.11-03131106.201408131735_all.deb http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.13.11.6-trusty/linux-headers-3.13.11-03131106-generic_3.13.11-03131106.201408131735_i386.deb http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.13.11.6-trusty/linux-image-3.13.11-03131106-generic_3.13.11-03131106.201408131735_i386.deb && sudo dpkg -i *.deb
    ```
  - If your system's architecture is **64-bit** (amd64), run this supercommand:

    ```
    sudo wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.13.11.6-trusty/linux-headers-3.13.11-03131106_3.13.11-03131106.201408131735_all.deb http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.13.11.6-trusty/linux-headers-3.13.11-03131106-generic_3.13.11-03131106.201408131735_amd64.deb http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.13.11.6-trusty/linux-image-3.13.11-03131106-generic_3.13.11-03131106.201408131735_amd64.deb && sudo dpkg -i *.deb
    ```

The supercommand above will download all the three **deb** files required for kernel installation in your system and then will install them.

Now that you've installed the kernel, you'll have to configure GRUB in order to be able to boot kernel **3.13.0-36-generic** by default (instead of booting your current 4.X kernel). For help about how to do it, please read the answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order).

Comment: I tried doing this and got: `E: Unable to locate package linux-image-3.13.0-36-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-3.13.0-36-generic'
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-36-generic` The error repeated for headers, signed-image, and tools but it wouldn't all fit into a comment.

Comment: @jimirings: I updated the answer in order to explain how to identify your operating system's architecture and, based on it, manually download the 3 correct kernel files and install them. Once you've done it, configure and update GRUB so when your system is restarted it will select kernel **3.13.0-36-generic** by default.

Answer (score 0):

This is [Freedesktop bug #92084](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92084). The message (`*ERROR* The master control interrupt lied (SDE)`) is a harmless warning and can be safely ignored.

Comment: Unfortunately, it cannot be ignored as it spams garbage all over your console when you are trying to type commands.