# Ubuntu 16.04 - Can't install grub customizer

Tags: 16.04

I just did a fresh install of `Ubuntu 16.04` and I can't install `grub-customizer`. Any thoughts?

```
root@aizo-Aspire-5750:~# apt-get install grub-customizer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package grub-customizer
```

Comment: It looks like this package was never included [in the repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=grub-customizer&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all). Please do a quick research first how other users installed the program before to avoid duplicate questions. Possible duplicate: [How do I change the GRUB boot order?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This package does not appear in the default repositories. [This](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer?field.series_filter=xenial) is the PPA.

In short:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Comment: I have Xubuntu 16.04 installed, and I can confirm that this works fine.  =)

Comment: Thank you, I was having some other problems too, so I just did another fresh install and this time everything worked fine :)