# Operating system boot manager for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I am still new to Ubuntu, in the sense of how to go about installing and finding programs. I dually installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside my Windows 7 professional. I want to play with Ubuntu till i can work with it, in the meantime i want my laptop to boot directly into Windows 7. At the moment the Ubuntu platform is the nr 1 on the bootorder list when the computer starts up. If I am not present to manually select windows, it automatically boots to Ubuntu. So, I have to be present after starting up, to manually choose Windows, a matter of irritation! How can I change that? Is there a program I can install to change the boot order? ? How? Step by step please for an stupid like me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the GRUB boot order?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a terminal, type `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`, and press `Enter`.
In the file that opens up find the line `GRUB_DEFAULT`. Now the value of that line should be set to `0`, change it to `1`.

Save the file pressing `Ctrl+o`, press `Enter` to confirm, and `Ctrl+x` to exit.

Run the command `sudo update-grub`.

The next time you restart the PC, if you don't touch anything when the boot menu shows, it should automatically start Windows.

Note that the value of `GRUB_DEFAULT` starts the OS identified in the boot menu starting from 0.

Comment: Your answer did the thing. I only had to play with the value. The Windows 10 were listed nr 6 on the boot menu, so I entered 6, which did not work. Then I entered 5 and it did the job! Thanks!! Solved!!!

Comment: How do I go about to mark it as answered? Or as accepted? I dont see any place to do that.

Comment: Ok, I found it! :)