# Erased Ubuntu partition, now computer will not boot

Tags: boot, windows, windows-7

A while back I created a partition on my hard drive for Ubuntu. I was dual booting for a bit. My options were Linux or Windows 7. Recently I erased my Ubuntu partition through windows and it worked. When I rebooted I got the message:

```
error: no such partition.
Entering rescue mode
Grub rescue>
```

So I read through some forums and found someone saying this worked for them, so I booted up my live copy of Ubuntu, opened a terminal and entered these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

When it completed, I rebooted, and was given a new message:

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  Status: 0xc000000e  

  Info: The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible.
```

So I placed my system repair disc in booted into it. Then it showed the Windows logo and wouldn't go past that. I am stuck. I have tried a lot of things and I have read a lot of forums, but I cannot find an answer.

Comment: The help you need now as nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: You have removed Ubuntu, so your question about booting Windows is off-topic here. Please refer to SuperUser.com for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Answer (score 2):

I can think of three solutions you could try.

1. Since grub replaced the boot manager for Windows, it may be as simple as toggling which drive to boot from within your UEFI settings, if your motherboard supports advance features which bypasses boot manager settings.
2. If that method fails, you could reinstall Ubuntu, and simply use it as a boot manager to mount Windows. By this I mean setting the newly reinstalled GRUB to boot Windows by default. Various solutions are provided [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order).
3. Restore the Windows boot manager with tools in the rescue disk. The steps are provided [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/restoring-windows-boot-manager-with-dual-boot/9b780fb2-3565-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5?auth=1).

Comment: Thank you!  I will try these and see what works. I really do appreciate your help.

Comment: Regarding item 1, if that were the case, I'm pretty sure OP would either see a Grub Rescue prompt or a BIOS message like "No bootable device found!". 2. That's way more complicated than necessary. Also, Ubuntu is not a boot manager (you're thinking of Grub), and a boot manager does not "mount" an OS (it _loads_ an OS). 3. Installing the Windows Boot Manager has nothing to do with Ubuntu, so OP should refer to SuperUser.com - that's why I downvoted this answer.

Comment: For 1, I was considering selecting a drive partition to boot from within UEFI, completely bypassing whatever boot manager is in place, which for me, would be the simplest short term solution. For 2, technical terms aside, reinstalling Ubuntu to restore Grub seemed to be more realistic given the technical skills demonstrated in this answer. For 3. I was providing additional solutions based on the evidence at hand for what tools the OP has at their disposal. I do not have the credentials to move questions to other sites, but would still like to help.

Comment: @Rewarp Oh, I see. Sorry I misunderstood. I can only revert my downvote if you make an edit to the answer, so you could maybe add a link to point 2, to show OP how to set the default Grub boot entry.

Comment: No worries. I am glad to clarify my position so others don't misunderstand. :-)