# Changing default boot option in grub2

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 10. Other family members of my family also use my pc. And they are not comfortable with Ubuntu as they are used to with Windows. Sometimes they face difficulties while selecting boot option from grub. Now my question is, can I edit grub2 and change the default boot option? If it is possible, how to do it?

Comment: Hope [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order) askUbuntu answer will be helpful

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/110738/304559 . also read the comment by geekQ there

Answer (score 6):

- Open a terminal window and execute:  `sudo nano /boot/grub/grub.cfg`
- Enter your password.
- In the file opened, find the text: `set default="0"`
- Number **0** is for the **first option**, number **1** for the **second one**, etc. Change the number for your choice.
- Save the file by pressing `CTRL+O` and exit by pressing `CRTL+X`.

This will change in every grub update. So, if you want to have it made permanently edit the file `/etc/default/grub` and set `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` to the number of your choice.

Comment: Just edit `/etc/default/grub` without touching grub.cfg and run:
`grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Comment: In Ubuntu you can update Grub2 just running `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Editing `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` is not recommended. `/etc/default/grub` is there for a reason.

Comment: I tried this way. But after updating grub2 it's all the same as before.

Comment: So I told last two lines at my answer.