# How to INSTALL kernel 4.4 which no longer resides on the system and then remove kernel 4.10 from ubuntu 16.04

Tags: downgrade, bluetooth-speaker

My bluetooth audio arrangement works with 4.4.0-7x but no kernel that I've tried in between that and now 4.10.0-32 and beyond. It's an IHB-23 speaker system that shows up as a headset. On somewhere after 4.4.0-77 or so, something caused the behavior to change FROM:
pair, connect, show up as an audio device that can be set to ADP and actually have audio routed to it.
TO:
pair, connect, show up as an audio device without ADP capability (and only mono) but no audio stream is ever routed to the device. When an attempt is made to select it, the selection appears to change but actually remains at the previous setting. Crazy making. I wish to return to the older kernel.

Would the best way be to scrap the current installation altogether and try to grab a copy of Ubuntu 16.04.0 or 1 and resinstall afresh? Or is there a simple method for installing linux 4.4.0.7x which no longer resides on the system - the headers and images were removed some time ago ... before I decided to try using the system as my "sound" server, more or less.

Thanks for any assistance, this has been pushing my buttons for a while now.

Comment: I would even consider looking into this problem formally, but have never paid any attention to whatever bug tracking/resolution methodology is in vogue. Hints about the right approach to filing and working on bugs would thus be a boon.

Comment: You might just be able to download and install them:  https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/kernel/linux-image-4.4.0-77-generic

Answer (score 2):

Check that `linux-image-generic` is installed by running `sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic`, which if necessary will install the latest 4.4 kernel, currently 4.4.0.104.109.

The simplest way to reboot into the 4.4 kernel, is to reboot and press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and select the 4.4 kernel at the `grub menu`. Older kernels may be listed in a sub menu as `Advanced options for Ubuntu` or `Previous Linux Versions`. Alternatively `sudo nano /etc/default/grub && sudo update-grub` to comment out `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` and `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0`, write the file <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and exit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, `update-grub` will then run. After `update-grub` the grub menu should not be hidden when rebooting.

If everything works fine with the 4.4 kernel you can remove all the installed 4.10 kernel packages. See [How do I remove old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/a/100953/723193) for several methods to remove unwanted kernel packages.

Instead of removing the newer kernels you could change the [GRUB_DEFAULT](https://askubuntu.com/a/110738/723193). `grep menuentry_id_option /boot/grub/grub.cfg` will provide a list of viable values to choose from. For my oldest kernel I could use `GRUB_DEFAULT=gnulinux-4.8.17-galliumos-advanced-850a858b-1b7d-4451-8b00-541e3d314ee4`

Answer (score 1):

Install `linux-image-generic`, which will install the latest 4.4 kernel, reboot into the 4.4 kernel, and then if everything works fine you can remove all the installed 4.10 kernel packages (see for example `apt list --installed | grep linux` for a list).