# Replace Linux GRUB, boot Windows by default with Windows Boot Manager, keeping Linux installed

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, grub2, windows

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 as a dual boot after Windows 10. Now, when the laptop starts or restarts, it boots into Linux by default after showing the GRUB menu.

But I want to boot Windows normally by default, like before using Windows Boot Manager, replacing Linux Grub, but also want to keep Linux installed,

I want to boot Linux from BIOS Boot Manager only when needed.
Please help me.

Edit: I know that the boot order can be changed and can make Windows boot default in the Linux GRUB menu, but I don't want the GRUB menu to be shown while booting to Windows, as it takes some seconds more to boot Windows, since I'll boot Windows more and Linux less.

**Probably solution 1**: (this method works, but I'm not sure what this actually does, want more reliable solution)

From Windows:

1. *Settings* → *Recovery* → *Advanced* *Startup* → *Restart Now*

   Or Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> while restarting Windows to access the "Advanced Startup" menu.
2. *Troubleshoot* → *Command Prompt*:

   ```
   MOUNTVOL Z: /S
   BCDBoot C:\Windows
   ```

Update 1: This will disable Windows Recovery Environment. Enable WinRE by:

1. <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Yes
4. Reagentc / Enable

This will enable Windows Recovery Environment again.

Comment: I think your best option is instead to change the boot order in Grub - so that Windows is the default option. See this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order

Comment: You may also want to look into how Windows Boot Option works I do not think you fully understand how it works.

Comment: And in any modern uEFI based computer (something from a decade ago or newer) with the OSes properly installed in uEFI mode you can select each one independently at uEFI settings > Boot menu. So, you can always boot Windows directly. Change it back to "Ubuntu" (Grub) in order to boot Ubuntu (also Windows from the Grub menu if you want).

Comment: The answer to what you want to do would be on the Windows' side. Personally I would just set windows  to be the default on grub (but that's just me). But by google searching "windows boot manager dual boot", I see some results of what you are describing. I don't the rules here about linking external sites, nor am I confident enough to vouch for them because I don't live in the Windows world, so I'm hesitant about sharing those links. But what you want is there. Essentially this is more of a Windows question. In response to your edit, you can set that grub menu timeout down to your desire