# Tried installing ubuntu on ssd failed

Tags: boot, 22.04

I had a copy of Windows installed on my fusion drive

I wanted to switch to Ubuntu completely, So I prepared a bootable USB Drive for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, and installed it on my HDD.

Then later I faced many performance issues with my current installation, So i tried installing Ubuntu on my SSD with my bootable usb Drive.

Installation Finished with no errors, but when i boot up on my SSD,
Ubuntu starts on the HDD Drive. It just shows the SSD folder with Error sign on the swapfile and root folder.

Both the times while installing, I used erase disk and install and chose the respective disk.
Why both the boot options lands me to the Ubuntu OS installed in HDD?

[image: img]

Comment: Please be precise with details; Ubuntu 22 refers to Ubuntu Core 22? but you tagged 22.04?  Ubuntu's *year* based products (22) are a server *flavor* built from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server, which has advantages yes, but it's also a *cutdown* product thus has some differences/restrictions. You tagged a different system to what your question mentions so please clarify. You also gave no specific details; a server system? (22 or 22.04) desktop system (22.04)?  Did your installation indicate the boot loader was on the device you wanted it on during the pre-install summary?

Comment: Look at the SSD's EFI files -- there probably are none. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Grub installs to wrong disk. Do add yourself to the "Does this affect me?" list on the bug.
There are workarounds/solutions in the bug comments. Your other problem now is
that your host system probably will not boot without the external SSD (since
needed grub files are on it). Another ancient bug, 384633 might then affect you, when grub.cfg initially gets created with the /dev/sdc2 instead of a UUID.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop uses the `ubiquity` installer, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server uses `subiquity`, some *flavors* use `calamares` etc.. and you weren't specific as to which Ubuntu 22.04 LTS you installed (which ISO, desktop? server? alternate/canary? though that's unlikely etc).  FYI:  If it's the bug @ubfan1 mentioned; how you write your ISO to thumb-drive influences the results; if written using QA-tested procedures it should not happen  (note: I have more experience with Desktop installers but you didn't specify)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have two Ubuntu installations on two devices, an HDD and an external SSD (correct me if I'm wrong)

to boot from the external SSD you have you go to boot options menu of your device and select the external device

there are really good tutorials on how to change boot options and each device has it's own way of entering BIOS/UEFI boot menu. you can take a look at this [answer on how to change boot options on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order)

Btw booting from an external SSD can be tricky sometimes, it may disconnect for a millisecond and your device is shutdown...

Answer (score 2):

`/root/` and `swapfile` are owned by root, not accessible for the normal user.

Open a terminal and type `ls -l /` and you will see a lot of `root root` and `drwx------` on some of them

*...the latter is the `chown` flags saying `d` for dirs and `rwx` [ read, write, execute ] for user, group and others, with `-` for not allowed) - when "not allowed" for current user these show up with the red X in "files" (nautilus)*

**So: this is nothing "failed", fully normal.**