# Downgraded Kernel in Ubuntu 20.04 to 5.4, ubuntu will not boot now

Tags: boot, 20.04, kernel, downgrade

https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-downgrade-the-kernel-on-ubuntu-20-04-to-the-5-4-lts-version/26459

^ Following that thread, I downgraded kernel to version 5.4, as something I was working on required an LTS version. Rebooted after the upgrade, and now ubuntu just freezes with the cursor in the top left like this:

Loading linux 5.4.0-1084-aws ...

Loading initial ramdisk ...

__

How can I fix this? Can I upgrade kernel back to it's prior version without accessing desktop? I would rather not have to make an image and wipe all of my work.

Comment: Can you get the grub menu, which allows you to choose which installed kernel to use? Usually you press Esc or left shift after the UEFI screen.

Comment: Yes I accessed that. What command do I use to selct kernel versions? Haven't found anything on that yet.

Comment: I saved a backup of /etc/default/grub as well before the changes, How can I access that?

Comment: On the grub menu select "advanced options for Ubuntu" and then pick the entry that starts with Ubuntu, has the old kernel in it, and doesn't say recovery mode.

Comment: Thanks. that fixed it. Still haven't found a reason for the initial issue of not being able to roll back to kernel 5.4.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the GRUB boot order?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order)