# Ubuntu 22.04.3 Kernel broke the brightness

Tags: kernel, 22.04, brightness, toshiba-satellite, toshiba

I've just updated the system and with the update came the kernel **6.2.0**.

I restarted my labtop and the next thing I knew is that the brightness broke and won't get any lower from the highest possible brightness level.

I'm using **Toshiba Satellite L750**

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I boot with an older kernel version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long-term solution: Please file a bug report for the regression: `ubuntu-bug linux` while the brightness control is inoperative.

Temporary workaround: Reboot. [Expose the GRUB menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time), select an older kernel. That's why the older kernel is there.

Comment: Is there's a way to set the older kernel as the default for now?

Comment: Yes there is: https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order