Changing the order in Grub
Recently i added Linux Mint 22 in a 2nd partition in my laptop.
I have installed Linux Ubuntu 24.04 before.
My question is:
How can i change the order of the different versions of Linux.
I want Ubuntu as the default, but right now Linux Mint is the first in the list.
Thank you guys.
Negrazo

Have a look here https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order

Boot into Ubuntu and run sudo grub-install That uses a lot of defaults but if working UEFI install will reinstall grub & make that install first in boot order. Note that major update to other installs, resets them to first in boot order. So you may have to repeat after major grub update. A standard grub update only updates grub menu.  I like to change name in UEFI, but Mint also uses "ubuntu" as UEFI entry, even though not official entry. I like to change name: #GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian to something like
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="Mint"  and reinstall of grub.

I regularly re-install OSes for QA testing purposes, and I almost never want the last installed OS to own the booting process (yet last installed will almost always own it), so my method is to ignore it, and as I boot into each OS as part of the procedure (required to ensure they're not corrupted by the install), I boot into the one I want to have control of boot process; and just have that OS install grub (overwriting the last installed OS' grub).. ie. I'm suggesting booting into Ubuntu and have it take ownership of boot (grub-install).  This is as @oldfred suggests !

To have another option in the grub menu be used as default, you may  change GRUB_DEFAULT= below to a higher number.
You may also select options from submenus; I can't seem to find any recent accepted answers showing that though; I THINK it should be ...=2>1 for second menu entry and first suboption there.
Here: show the menu 3 seconds, then go for first entry (note update-grub !):
$ head  -n 8 /etc/default/grub
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=3

Also note: if you change /boot/grub/grub.cfg directly, it will be rewritten at next time the OS does update-grub (e.g. as new kernel gets added).
